# Sort a file preserving the header as first position with bash

Tags: awk, sed

When sorting a file, I am not preserving the header in its position:

file_1.tsv

```
Gene   Number  
a       3
u       7
b       9
```

```
sort -k1,1 file_1.tsv
```

Result:

```
a     3
b     9
Gene  Number
u     7
```

So I am tryig this code:

```
sed '1d' file_1.tsv | sort -k1,1 > file_1_sorted.tsv 
first='head -1 file_1.tsv' 
sed '1 "$first"' file_1_sorted.tsv
```

What I did is to remove the header and sort the rest of the file, and then trying to add again the header. But I am not able to perform this last part, so I would like to know how can I copy the header of the original file and insert it as the first row of the new file without substituting its actuall first row.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this as well :

```
{ head -1; sort; } < file_1.tsv
```

** Update **

For macos :

```
{ IFS= read -r header; printf '%s\n' "$header" ; sort; } < file_1.tsv
```

Comment: This did not work for me.  It printed only the first line without sorting the remainder.
   > GNU bash, version 5.0.16(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0)

Comment: To sort the file in place perhaps `sed -i -e 'e(head -1;sort) <file' -e Q file`? I'm not sure if command grouping using `{...}` or `(...)` makes any difference?

Comment: @EricBolinger, `head --version` gives `head (GNU coreutils) 8.30`, maybe `head` on macos has taken all the lines.

Comment: Thanks Philippe.  Indeed this `head` executable was ported from FreeBSD to Mac OS X.  It does not understand the `--version` option.  But running `strings` on the binary file yields: `$FreeBSD: src/usr.bin/head/head.c,v 1.20 2007/01/11 20:23:01 brooks Exp $` which looks like a CVS-injected record.

Answer (score 4):

a simpler `awk`

```
$ awk 'NR==1{print; next} {print | "sort"}' file
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ head -1 file; tail -n +2 file | sort
```

Output:

```
Gene   Number  
a       3
b       9
u       7
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  first=$0
  next
}
{
  val=(val?val ORS:"")$0
}
END{
  print first
  print val | "sort"
}
'  Input_file
```

***Logical explanation:***

- Check condition `FNR==1` to see if its first line; then save its values to variable and move on to next line by `next`.
- Then keep appending all lines values to another variable with new line till last line.
- Now come to `END` block of this code which executes when Input_file is done being read, there print first line value and put `sort` command on rest of the lines value there.

Answer (score 2):

This will work using any awk, sort, and cut in any shell on every UNIX box and will work whether the input is coming from a pipe (when you can't read it twice) or from a file (when you can) and doesn't involve awk spawning a subshell:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{print (NR>1), $0}' file | sort -k1,1n -k2,2 | cut -f2-
```

The above uses awk to stick a 0 at the front of the header line and a 1 in front of the rest so you can sort by that number then whatever other field(s) you want to sort on and then remove the added field again with a cut. Here it is in stages:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{print (NR>1), $0}' file
0   Gene   Number
1   a       3
1   u       7
1   b       9

$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{print (NR>1), $0}' file | sort -k1,1n -k2,2
0   Gene   Number
1   a       3
1   b       9
1   u       7

$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{print (NR>1), $0}' file | sort -k1,1n -k2,2 | cut -f2-
Gene   Number
a       3
b       9
u       7
```